# Properly control compositor's output file names when using command line rendering

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, command-line

My compositor looks like:

[image]

It's simply two render layers, rendered to two separate files.

But when I run:

```
blender -b test.blend  -E BLENDER_EEVEE -f 1
```

It outputs:

```
...
Saved: /Users/raincole/Google Drive/Painting/3D/Blender/Reference for 2D/output/Sphere0001.png
Saved: /Users/raincole/Google Drive/Painting/3D/Blender/Reference for 2D/output/Cube0001.png
Fra:1 Mem:89.09M (0.00M, Peak 175.32M) | Time:00:08.33 | Sce: Scene Ve:0 Fa:0 La:0
Saved: '/tmp/0001.png'
```

...three files, `output/Sphere0001.png`, `Cube0001.png` and `/tmp/0001.png`. What I expected are two files `output/Sphere.png` and `output/Cube.png`. What did I do wrong here?

Comment: You can't disable to save the default rendering *(Output Properties (Printer Icon) > Output Panel > Output Path)* so there is nothing wrong, that's expected. Default Rendering (without comp) + 2 File Output Nodes = 3 Images

Comment: @brockmann okay, but where does "0001" of "Cube0001" come from? I didn't specify serial number like "Cube####". If it's the default behavior, how can I disable that?

Comment: It's the frame number (Frame 1). Again, you **can't disable that behavior** - long time feature request. I suggest set it to jpg if you want to save some time (a few milliseconds).

Comment: Got it. It's weird that blender doesn't support this. Guess I'll just rename them from shell script.

Comment: What exactly you'd like to rename?

Comment: Just remove the 0001 part

Comment: Removing the file would be easier...